# How to specify form field and file type with Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to upload an image using requests module (Python 3). Sadly, the server answers my request with an error, saying that I should only upload files of type jpg, png or gif. 
I guess I should fill every field of the form, but I want to figure out how despite all my tests.

Here is the HTML form :

```
<form class="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?action=upload" method="post">
            <h3>Envoyez votre image !</h3>
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="15360000" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="img" size="30" type="file" />
    <input value="Envoyer" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I use this Python code :

```
with open(image, 'rb') as img:
    toup = {'img': (os.path.basename(image), img)}
    res= requests.post('http://url/?action=upload', files = toup)
```

How can I fill the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` field and specify the type of the uploaded file?

Comment: Are you certain the file you're attempting to upload is jpg, png or gif?  
Can you provide some more code, maybe a running sample?

Comment: yes, I'm sure it's a jpg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [set the mime type](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) of the file:

```
toup = {'img': (os.path.basename(image), img, 'image/jpeg')}
```

To get exact MIME of the file, you can use [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) library.

Comment: That's what I was lookink for, how to specify the mimetype. It works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

MAX_FILE_SIZE seems to be a normal HTTP POST data:

```
with open(image, 'rb') as img:
    toup = {'img': (os.path.basename(image), img)}
    res= requests.post('http://url/?action=upload', files = toup, data={'MAX_FILE_SIZE': '15360000'})
```

Comment: It doesn't work neither. I stille have the answer about file type. If someone wants to try, it is with http://pix.toile-libre.org :
    `res= requests.post('http://pix.toile-libre.orgl/?action=upload', files = toup, data={'MAX_FILE_SIZE': '15360000'})`